# How to push a theme update for a custom theme used on multiple independant self hosted sites?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I feel like this should be straightforward but by all accounts seems to cause a lot of problems and is steeped in black magic..

I have developed a custom theme, I want to use this theme on several websites, and I want to be able to update the theme occasionally and have these updates pushed to/detected by those websites.

I've explored a variety of similar questions/answers here, as well as various plugins and tutorials to this effect, all unfortunately to absolutely no avail.

What do I need to include in the theme code, and what is the correct method of pushing an available update?

Just to clarify; I don't want this theme to be public or hosted on the WP repository.

Many thanks!

Comment: That's not straightforward  at all tho. In short, natively from the theme itself you can't. But depending on your hosting provider you could set up a pipeline. For example AWS let you set up through GitHub a pipeline via Code Pipeline. Any changes done on GitHub would be pushed to any live sites that are using this GitHub repository.

Comment: Thank you for the response - I'll look into this functionality. Cheers!